# How to access emails from contacts app in your application?

Tags: cocoa-touch

I need to send emails to a list of IDs from the contact application, from my application. Is there a way to access the contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is example code for doing basically this [here](http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/09/19/access-the-address-book/). The example is accessing the phone numbers rather than the email addresses.

Where the example is using kABPersonPhoneProperty you will want to be using kABPersonEmailProperty instead.

Answer (score 0):

hi thanx for the link , the example says to add the AddressBook.framework and AddressBookUI.framework frameworks , though i added the AddressBook.framework , AddressBookUI.framework is not available in the framwork folder .. i tried searching it in /Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework , but the platform folder is also empty ...